# AngularJS Data Binding issue on Internet Explorer compatibility mode using Curly Braces

Tags: angularjs

I followed http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie when developing my web page. But in IE8/9/10 with compatibility Mode, the page is showing up with {{}} and the data is not getting binded. I am using angular-1.0.5.min.js version and have the following.

Please help on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Usually if angular isn't binding, it's because your code threw an exception while initializing.

Comment: any errors in the browser console? Have you tried standards mode in IE  8/9/10?

Comment: No errors. In standard mode, it works. Also if I have IE developer tool open in compatibility mode, it works.

Answer (score 11):

When I find something only works with developer tools open, the usual culprit turns out to be that I'm using console.log(...).

Is it possible that you are using console.log() or similar calls that are only available when the developer tools are open?

When developer tools aren't open, console is undefined, and scripts fall over when you call console.log.

If this is the problem and you want to keep the log calls in your code you could stub out console.log like:

```
window.console = window.console || {};
window.console.log = window.console.log || function() {};
```

Comment: Then mark it as the solution.
+1 to this answer. I had the same issue, and it is inherently difficult to debug - since it disappears the moment you try to debug it...

Answer (score 0):

Try bootstrapping angular manually

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Manual bootstrapping didn't work either. Please refer to my original question to see the code I have.